# passing and getting too large query string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i integrating with an software, where they sending their document to my url with too large query string value. i.e. more than 75000 char for a parameter.  i am in a R&D phase to check whether integration is works.  i came to know that browsers will limit the query string.  i want to get their document into to my server. i google but not get the answer. the url is in following fashion

```
Http:\\myurl?document=thierdocument in base64 encoded format
```

guide me to overcome the problem

Comment: Why isn't this data in a HTTP Post?

Comment: sure i will if get an relative answers to solve my problem.  the software which i am integrating is asking in this fashion. how can i handle it in query string manner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not going to work. The query string is limited to a few thousand characters depending on the browser (i.e. [2083 characters for IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/)). Use a `HTTP POST` instead and put the document in binary format in the body of the request.

The main idea of a URL was to be a *Uniform Resource* ***Locator***, not to pass all the data as part of the URL itself. You cannot work around the browser limits on URLs (neither should you arguably) - an alternative could be passing the document id in form of a number or Guid, then looking up that document to process as part of your page.

Comment: their integration is in this fashion. so i want to work out in this way only. since they are giving, i think there will some possibility to do this. if your are having any idea about it share me

Comment: We found that the user also using HTTP post for pushing resumes

Comment: I have to pass string when i open the new page, because the page is depend on this string?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to move the data from query string, to post form.

My suggestion is to move the data from query string, to post form.

Why ?
one reason is the the url data, including your big string, is used to know if the page is going to cached by the browser or not. So I think that browser him self have a problem remeber this big string.

other reason is that this url is travel as it is, a big one, and is very possible to not reach  the target.

The 2083 charatercs in IE I think that is refered only on URL, not on the included data.

Comment: the software which i am integrating is asking in this fashion. how can i handle it in query string manner

Comment: You can't.  The software you are integrating sucks if it can't handle POST data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it using `POST` query.

Taken from [What is the limit on QueryString / GET / URL parameters?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/forms/what-is-the-limit-on-querystring/get/url-parameters.html)

> The spec for URL length does not dictate a minimum or maximum URL
>   length, but implementation varies by browser. On Windows: Opera
>   supports ~4050 characters, IE 4.0+ supports exactly 2083 characters,
>   Netscape 3 -> 4.78 support up to 8192 characters before causing errors
>   on shut-down, and Netscape 6 supports ~2000 before causing errors on
>   start-up.